# lightdm and deepin desktop login issues

Tags: login, lightdm, desktop-environments

I thought I'd give Deepin Desktop a go, so I went through the setup instructions given here [deepin setup](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-18-04)

The desktop is nice, but I now cannot select a different desktop from the lightdm drop-down list (e.g. Unity, Ubuntu on Wayland, Ubuntu). Lightdm says there are 'too many arguments' i.e. 4 including Deepin DE instead of the 3 that it expects.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling lightdm?  `sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm`  Just a thought.

Comment: Tried that, no joy. Still the same error message "unsupported number of arguments". Only logs in if you select 'Deepin' from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution of sorts...

I just had to switch to the basic Gnome Display Manager GDM3 instead of LightDM, with the following terminal command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` , which brings up a selection box

For some reason GDM copes better with Deepin Desktop than LightDM does - I am now able to login to other desktops as well as Deepin, including Gnome and Unity.

Comment: I would be just as interested in knowing why LightDM failed like that and not allow you to choose the other DEs.  Anyway, +1 for good troubleshooting!  =)

Comment: Thanks :) ! It's all a bit of a mystery to me, so happy if anyone else wants to contribute a better solution which keeps lightdm in place...

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with the session-wrapper command used for deepin. Within **/usr/share/lightdm/lghtdm.conf.d/60-deepin.conf** the session-wrapper is changed to **/usr/sbin/deepin-session** and deepin-session appears to be the default used wrapper. It tries to use it for the ubuntu user-session.

Taken from **/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log**

```
Running command /usr/sbin/deepin-session env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

If you want, you can change the session-wrapper to lightdm-session for the ubuntu user-session as part of your **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf**

```
[SeatDefaults]
session-wrapper=lightdm-session
```

For me, this change enabled me to login with the Ubuntu user session once again.

Answer (score 0):

Time to time i have the same problem, lightdm crash on pam services.
I use `sudo lightdm` from terminal when happen and then you can use it as before. But this is just temporary fix, there must be something wrong in PAM.
And time to time there is segmentation fault.

See:

```
/var/log/lightdm
```